# Can't sign into Xbox Live test account using sandbox

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp, xbox-one, xbox-live

We are porting our Unity3D game to UWP and we had hit obstacle related to Xbox Live sandbox environment.
We had done following things:

- Created new UWP app in Windows Dev Dashboard
- Requested access to Xbox Live Creators program
- Authorized our Xbox Live accounts in dashboard
- Set given Sandbox ID  in Xbox One console & Windows 10 PC
- Associated our app with store in Visual Studio
- Created *xboxservices.config* file in project and set its *Build Action* to *Content* and *Copy to Output Directory* to *Copy Always*

  ```
  {
    "TitleId" : 1859112156,
    "PrimaryServiceConfigId" : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-00006ecfccdc"
  }
  ```

After all this steps we are getting following problems:

**On Xbox One**

When we try to sign into Xbox Live in-game using *XboxLiveUser.SignInAsync* function (from *Microsoft.Xbox.Services.System* namespace) we are getting following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Arg_InvalidOperationException
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x4511ee
at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x451168
...
```

**On Windows 10 PC**

When we try to sign into Xbox Live in-game we are getting popup with error *0x87DD0005*
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Xbox Live Creators Program for your game, then you should add **"XboxLiveCreatorsTitle"** into your *xboxservices.config* file like

```
{
    "TitleId": 1859112156,
    "PrimaryServiceConfigId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-00006ecfccdc",
    "XboxLiveCreatorsTitle": true
}
```

Refer from [Associate your Visual Studio project with your Xbox Live enabled title](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-live/get-started-with-creators/develop-creators-title-with-visual-studio#4-associate-your-visual-studio-project-with-your-xbox-live-enabled-title):

> 6. XboxLiveCreatorsTitle must be set to true for titles in the Xbox Live Creators Program as it changes the sign-in method to work for titles in the Xbox Live Creators Program.

Besides, you may also check you [Sandbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-live/xbox-live-sandboxes#switch-your-pcs-development-sandbox) and [Test accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-live/get-started-with-creators/authorize-xbox-live-accounts). After switching your PC's development sandbox, you can log in to **Xbox App** with you test account first to see if they are work well.

And also, before testing, don't forget to **publish your Xbox Live service configuration** by clicking the **Test** button on the Xbox Live configuration page.

Comment: Thank you so much!
Adding _"XboxLiveCreatorsTitle": true_ solved issue. 
I looked at different MS pages but somehow I missed it..